# Php - Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

First I was have:

```
 public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result();
        $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $tasks;
    }
```

and this function have a problem with `get_result()` so instead get_result now I write function with BIND and FETCH:

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $tasks = array();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);

            $stmt->fetch();
            $tasks["id"] = $id;
            $tasks["task"] = $task;
            $tasks["status"] = $status;
            $tasks["created_at"] = $created_at;
            $stmt->close();
            return $tasks;
    }
```

But on other file index.php now I get:`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in <b>/home/agroagro/public_html/agroMobile/v1/index.php</b> on line <b>155</b><br />`

so there is a code:

```
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
            global $user_id;
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // fetching all user tasks
            $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["tasks"] = array();

            // looping through result and preparing tasks array
            while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    <--HERE IS LINE 155 and ERROR
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["id"] = $task["id"];
                $tmp["task"] = $task["task"];
                $tmp["status"] = $task["status"];
                $tmp["createdAt"] = $task["created_at"];
                array_push($response["tasks"], $tmp);
            }

            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

I try to solve this all day and dont work... Can somebody tell me what is exactly the problem here now?

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: You are double fetching it... `$tasks` already contains your result...

Comment: how to solve , what I need to change in code?

Comment: `stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);` + `$tasks['id'] = $id` just looks messy, IMO. Just fetch the row(s) as an assoc array from the off

Comment: please write this as an naswer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested code):

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($user_id));

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
    global $user_id;
    $response = array();
    $db = new DbHandler();

    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["tasks"] = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });
```

Comment: hm, now I get: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() in <b>/home/agroagro/public_html/agroMobile/include/DbHandler.php</b> on line <b>281</b><br />

Comment: @LaraBeginer I was using PDO in my example, since it looked like you were using PDO... With mysqli the syntax should differ slightly, but the principle stays the same... Load your results in the method `getAllUserTasks()`, add them to `$response["tasks"]` in the other part of your code.

Comment: @LaraBeginer Nice statement... Since you are not paying me; NO